# The window_handles is not updating after site update

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a website workflow process by using selenium. But after logging into site the new window opened is not added to the window_handles list so it appears as if the page has never changed. The code below shows how the window_handles is the same before and after the login. This is a issue because I cant find web objects with the `find_element(By.XPATH,"")` function on new page. driver seems to think the original page has been closed and it has for the login page.

Does any anyone have any advice on this? Mainly dealing with automating websites with login pages

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Create an instance of the web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Change to the appropriate web driver 
(e.g., Firefox(), Safari(), etc.)

# Open a webpage
driver.get('https://3gissvrdev.xxxxxxxx.com/3GISWebJS/')
print(driver.window_handles)


# Find an element and click it
user_name =  driver.find_element("id", "usernameField") 

user_name.send_keys("CarpenCD")

pw=driver.find_element(By.ID, "passwordField")
pw.send_keys("xxxxxxxxxxx")
#pw=driver.find_element("id", "passwordField")

SigninButton=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"signinButton\"]")
SigninButton.click()

#use this section of code to give time for web page to load after 
logging on
in1=input('are you ready to move on')
if in1 == 'y':
    print(driver.window_handles)
    print(driver.window_handles[-1])


    #switch_window(0) 
    #Query=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"d481e7896cf443e3aae933d31fc5a1d4\"]/paper-button/span")
    #Query.click()

# Close the browser
#driver.quit()
```

Output

[image]

Comment: You are facing a race condition